# Type casting in PHPDocumentor

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Is there any type casting for PHPDocumentor in PHPStorm?
My PHPStorm IntelliSense is stubborn and i need to teach him how to behave.

This is my case:

I have a manager that instantiates classes that all extend same class.
Usually i would cast my class after it was returned but PHP doesn't know how to do that.
IntelliSense and PHPDocumentor support would be enough for me but i don't know how to type cast.

This is the code:

```
class Plugin 
{

}

class HelloPlugin extends Plugin
{
    public function hello()
    {

    }
}

class PluginManager 
{
    /** @var HelloPlugin */
    public $helloPlugin;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->helloPlugin = $this->getPlugin('HelloPlugin');

        // Here my PHPStorm IntelliSense doesn't provide 'hello()' function for 'helloPlugin' because return type overwrote original type
        // I get error: method 'hello' not found in class
        $this->helloPlugin->hello();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $pluginClass
     * @return Plugin
     */
    function getPlugin($pluginClass)
    {
        return new $pluginClass;
    }

}
```

Comment: i don't think its a duplicate because this is not case with static functions, and that answer only works for static methods.

Comment: @tlenss Not really -- PHPDoc is already there (with correct type hint), but IDE overwrites it.

Comment: @LazyOne You are right.. somehow i thought he was calling a static factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it's actually possible :( , unless you rewrite your code somehow (just for PhpStorm ... no way).

Your code and PHPDoc is fine -- it's an IDE issue -- it temporarily (within that method only) overwrites manually provided type hint with the one it detects (it will work fine in other methods). Please vote: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17047

Comment: hi thanks for answering, it was a typo i fixed it. but error is still here.
i will vote on your link.
hope we get it soon. 
i will search more then i will mark your answer as the right one if i don't find any solutions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario its not weird. You have put type Plugin|HelloPlugin , but this needs to be dynamic. I guess this is just an issue with PHPStorm.

Comment: @Alvaro Nothing weird -- check value of `@return` tag for `getPlugin` types in your code and original/mine :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I hadn't noticed the typo and I had been playing with the code.

Comment: I'd agree that it is the return tag of getPlugin() that is driving the behavior you're seeing.  I'd further argue that a method's return type *should* take precedence over a property's var type, as shown in the example.  At _runtime_, it certainly would take precedence :-)